# What is the simplest way to create a pretty printed xml in a biztalk SendPort

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk

An older interface of us is a simple receiveport + sendport with mapping.

The output is XML and if you open it the xml is on 1 line.

The software that processes it has no issues with this but, when an error occurs it usually displays "row 1 colomn 61258".

When an end user opens the file and pretty prints the file, he looses sight of were the error is at.

i tried adding " " to the xslt but it seems this didn't work and kept the outputfile in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Well...I would recommend you leave it as is and focus on preventing such errors.

There are a lot of things that can go wonky when processing Xml and you can't really count on the line number being accurate.  Even the column number can be off depending on where the error occurred and what what type it was.

However, if users are insisting you do this, you set the Indent property on the Map design surface to True.

Comment: So, after insisting i did toggle this flag and ran into a small issue. It worked fine in dev and on small files but on bigger files, the indent would stop afterx lines. The examples i looked at varied slightly, but it stopped worked well past 2000 lines. It also did a clean break, stopping the indenting after starting a new repeating element and not in the middle of it. I didn't see anything in the data to cause it and if i pretty print it with notepad++ it works. Is this a certain limitations i am running into?